# Mapping custom operations on resources other than HTTP provides with REST through JAX-RS (Jersey)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am providing a common service which has been currently exposed through JAX-WS with JAX-RS (Jersey) now.

The given service has operations on items similar to those in HTTP, Create, Find, Update. These can be mapped to `GET`, `POST` and `PUT`. But I do have operations on items like revise, localize etc.

An item is always comprised of a system-generated ID and Revision.

The first ones are really easy to implement:

```
GET /items/{type}/{id}/{revision} -- revision is optional
PUT /items/{type}/{id}/{revision} -- updates the content of a revision
POST /items/{type} -- creates a completely new item
```

How to map revise, localize without breaking semantics of REST?
I was used to use Spring's `@RequestMapping` `header` value and thought I could do the following with `PUT`.

```
PUT /items/{type}/{id}/{revision}
Sub-Method: (REVISE, LOCALIZE, etc.)
```

This is not possible ith Jersey, though I do not even know if this is a good approach.

Advises highly recommended.

EDIT: `PUT` with a revise contradicts with the idempotency of the aforementioned method.